# How to add extra cambria font for CKEditor Font module in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, ckeditor, drupal-8

I am working on Drupal 8, and using CKEditor Font and Family module for adding font and size options in my CKEditor. I want to add extra Cambria font in font option. What can I do for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to install the Drupal 8 module [CKEditor Font Size and Family](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_font). Which will allow you to expose a new "Font(s)" selector.

I would also suggest you to read those articles which will help achieving your goal:

- [How to Install CKEditor Plugins in Drupal 8](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/how-to-install-ckeditor-plugins-in-drupal-8/)
- The unofficial [documentation of the Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/ckeditor-font-size-and-family)